# Pointer to main function in c

Tags: c, embedded

When we make a pointer to the main function and call it is it duplicating the data in the stack memory like in recursive or just point at it and start over.

Comment: There is no difference in this regard between `main` or any other function

Comment: Neither. Whenever you call a function, whether it is `main` or any other function, new information for the function is pushed onto the stack. It does not duplicate what is already there (that is, it does not directly copy what is already on the stack; the new data may be the same because the new call does the same things as the old call), nor is the stack pointer changed to point to the location of the original `main` information.

Comment: @EugeneSh. `main()` may miss the return statement

Comment: For an embedded system I suspect that what you are actually looking for is how to enforce a MCU reset, since that will restore all register values as well as the software.

Answer (score 4):

This is valid C code:

```
int main(void) {
    main();
}
```

If you compile and run it, you will notice it will crash with a segmentation fault. You're basically blowing up the stack. This shows it is actually consuming a bit of the stack on each nested call.

---

As a further example:

Like any recursive function, you need to have a mechanism that guarantees a recursion limit within the range of what your environment allows you to use.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc > 1) {
        main(--argc, ++argv);
        printf("%s\n", *argv);
    }
}
```

This will print all command line arguments in reverse order.

Comment: Wow! You beat me to the answer by two minutes. The example is virtually identical to mine except that I added a `%p` print of `__builtin_frame_address(0)` to show the stack pointer and `int (*ptr_to_main)(int,char **) = main;` and called via that.